# What does +$ do in this line and in general?

Tags: regular-expression

I have this code ^[a-zA-Z]+$ that is meant to isolate ONLY letters, and it only works after I added +$, before it also counted things like A33.
My question is, what does +$ do/mean?

Comment: It's not `+$` but `[a-zA-Z]+` and then `$`. `$` means end of line. `+` means one or more occurrences of the preceding pattern (`[a-zA-Z]`).

Comment: where can I learn more about things like these? for example about ^ ? + etc

Comment: You can start [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Comment: @guillermochamorro Note that online "fact sheets", like the one you point to, often tend to omit to tell you that what they are showing are in fact PCRE or similar regular expressions and not the ones supported by most Unix command line tools.

Comment: @MADS One start could be this other question on this site: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905)

Answer (score 1):

In an *extended regular expression* (the type supported by e.g. the `bash` shell), the `+` is a modifier on the preceding expression (`[a-zA-Z]`, which, by its own, matches a single character from the given set) which requires the expression to match at least once, but possibly many times.  The `$` is the "end of line anchor", meaning that after a non-empty string of characters in the ranges `a-z` or `A-Z`, there must be nothing else but the end of the line.

Likewise, the `^` (as used in your expression), is an anchor to the start of the line.

The string `A33` would not be matched by this expression, because the `33` bit at the end of the line is not allowed by it.  Without the `$`, the expression would match the string because the whole expression would match the `A` substring at the start.  Without the `+` (but with `$`), it would *not* match the string `AAA` since the expression would only allow for a single character.